# How to get missing value column name from couchbase

Tags: sql, nosql, couchbase, sql++

I'm running query which is don't have current day value, i have tried ifmissing() function to get the column name but it doesn't work some case i don't know the reason.

**My query is:**

```
SELECT SPLIT(DATE_ADD_STR(SPLIT (ev. auditDetail.createTime,'.')[0],7,‘hour'),‘T') [0],
    ADD (TONUMBER(SPLIT(SPLIT (ev.auditDetail.createTime, 'T')[1], ‘:')[0]),7) AS HOUR,
    COUNT (*) AS COUNT
    FROM data_KH ev
    WHERE type_ = ‘user’
    AND DATE_ADD_STR(SPLIT (ev. auditDetail.createTime,‘.')[0],7,‘hour’) >
    CLOCK_TZ (‘Asia/Bangkok', '1111-11-11‘)
    AND SPLIT (loginId,‘@‘)[1] NOT IN [‘yopmail.com', ‘ymail.com', ‘accoliteindia.com']
    GROUP BY SPLIT (DATE_ADD_STR(SPLIT(ev. auditDetail.createTime,'.')[0],7,'hour'),‘T‘) [0],
    ADD (TONUMBER (SPLIT (SPLIT (ev.auditDetail.createTime, ‘T')[1], ‘:')[0]),7)
    ORDER BY SPLIT (DATE_ADD_STR(SPLIT (ev. auditDetail.createTime,'.')[0],7,'hour'),‘T') [0],
    ADD (TONUMBER (SPLIT (SPLIT (ev. auditDetail.createTime, 'T')[1], ':')[0]),7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subquery results are ARRAY, If no results it will be 0 length (not MISSING).
There is EXIST/NOT EXIST on subquery results. As you need results too and don't want repeat query twice. You can use the following approach too.

CB 6.5 or above

```
WITH result AS (SELECT DATE_FORMAT_STR(crdate, "2020-01-01") AS date,
                       DATE_PART_STR(crdate, "hour") AS hour,
                       COUNT (1) AS count
                FROM data_KH AS ev
                LET crdate = DATE_ADD_STR(SPLIT(ev.auditDetail.createTime, ".")[0], 7, "hour")
                WHERE type_ = "user"
                    AND crdate > CLOCK_TZ ("Asia/Bangkok", "1111-11-11")
                    AND SPLIT (loginId,"@")[1] NOT IN ["yopmail.com", "ymail.com", "accoliteindia.com"]
                GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT_STR(crdate, "2020-01-01"), DATE_PART_STR(crdate, "hour"))
SELECT d.*
FROM (CASE WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(result) > 0 THEN result ELSE [{"date": CLOCK_TZ("Asia/Bangkok","2020-01-01"),
                                                      "hour":DATE_PART_STR(CLOCK_TZ("Asia/Bangkok"), "hour"),
                                                      "count":0}]
                                               END) AS d
ORDER BY d.date, d.hour;
```

Pre CB 6.50

```
SELECT d.*
FROM ARRAY_FLATTEN ((SELECT RAW CASE WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(result) > 0
                                    THEN result
                                    ELSE [{"date": CLOCK_TZ("Asia/Bangkok","2020-01-01"),
                                           "hour":DATE_PART_STR(CLOCK_TZ("Asia/Bangkok"), "hour"),
                                           "count":0}]
                                    END
                    LET result = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT_STR(crdate, "2020-01-01") AS date,
                                         DATE_PART_STR(crdate, "hour") AS hour,
                                         COUNT (1) AS count
                                  FROM data_KH AS ev
                                  LET crdate = DATE_ADD_STR(SPLIT(ev.auditDetail.createTime, ".")[0], 7, "hour")
                                  WHERE type_ = "user"
                                      AND crdate > CLOCK_TZ ("Asia/Bangkok", "1111-11-11")
                                      AND SPLIT (loginId,"@")[1] NOT IN ["yopmail.com", "ymail.com", "accoliteindia.com"]
                                  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT_STR(crdate, "2020-01-01"), DATE_PART_STR(crdate, "hour"))),1) AS d
ORDER BY d.date, d.hour;
```

You can also use STR_TO_TZ(ev.auditDetail.createTime,"Asia/Bangkok") instead DATE_ADD_STR(SPLIT(ev.auditDetail.createTime, ".")[0], 7, "hour")  https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html

Answer (score 1):

I have modified main query has sub query and created static result if no result found in main query

```
SELECT [{'$1':split (DATE_ADD_STR(SPLIT(clock_utc(),'.')[0],7,hour),'T')[0], COUNT':0,
HOUR' : add(TONUMBER(SPLIT (clock_utc('11:11:11'), ':')[0],7)}] AS ‘alterData’,
(SELECT SPLIT(DATE_ADD_STR(SPLIT (ev. auditDetail.createTime,'.')[0],7,‘hour'),‘T') [0],
    ADD (TONUMBER(SPLIT(SPLIT (ev.auditDetail.createTime, 'T')[1], ‘:')[0]),7) AS HOUR,
    COUNT (*) AS COUNT
    FROM data_KH ev
    WHERE type_ = ‘user’
    AND DATE_ADD_STR(SPLIT (ev. auditDetail.createTime,‘.')[0],7,‘hour’) >
    CLOCK_TZ (‘Asia/Bangkok', '1111-11-11‘)
    AND SPLIT (loginId,‘@‘)[1] NOT IN [‘yopmail.com', ‘ymail.com', ‘accoliteindia.com']
    GROUP BY SPLIT (DATE_ADD_STR(SPLIT(ev. auditDetail.createTime,'.')[0],7,'hour'),‘T‘) [0],
    ADD (TONUMBER (SPLIT (SPLIT (ev.auditDetail.createTime, ‘T')[1], ‘:')[0]),7)
    ORDER BY SPLIT (DATE_ADD_STR(SPLIT (ev. auditDetail.createTime,'.')[0],7,'hour'),‘T') [0],
    ADD (TONUMBER (SPLIT (SPLIT (ev. auditDetail.createTime, 'T')[1], ':')[0]),7)) AS ‘data’
```